# How to setup Linux and Windows 10 dualboot without access to BIOS?

Tags: debian, boot, windows, dual-boot, boot-loader

I want to dualboot Debian on Windows 10 laptop on which I don't have access to BIOS/UEFI settings. I do have access to boot menu (i guess it's technically part of the BIOS) so I can manually select where to boot but it would be inconvenient to have to do that every time I want boot to Debian since I'm going to be using it primarily. Apparently using Windows Boot Manager to boot to any OS other than Windows [does not anymore.](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/uefi/) I found [this article](https://dev.to/greenroommate/fix-gnu-linux-boot-loader-from-windows-10-129j) but I'm not sure how it interacts with secure boot which I obviously can't disable. A way to boot to Debian by default would be enough since I don't need to use Windows very often. Also reinstalling Windows is not an option.

Some additional information about my system:

- Windows 10 for education 64 bit
- UEFI with GPT
- Windows 10 and Debian (Debian not yet installed) will be on same SSD.
- Laptop is HP ProBook 445

Comment: You have to have UEFI/BIOS access to change settings. If not your system, but a schools, do you have permission to add Linux? If so, then they should let you change the needed settings in UEFI. If not it is a major security violation.

Comment: Yes, it's a laptop i got from school for the entire period i'm going to be attending the school. I got permission to install Linux on it since after I return the laptop, it's going to be reset anyway. Also if I mess something up, the laptop could be reset. I don't think anybody in the school even has the BIOS password.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with option 3 of your first link:
Install grub2 as your primary bootloader on the disk.

The article states that the windows bootloader will not chainload Linux. So the other way will probably work.

AFAIK Debian has a signed EFI bootloader that should work in that constellation.

Comment: In the article, it says that "choose to install GRUB to the MBR (or disk, in this case) and make it the main bootloader for your PC.". This would suggest that I need to edit boot order in BIOS. However it also says that "You can add the Windows boot menu to the GRUB2 EFI boot menu – in this case, you’ll see GRUB’s boot menu when your PC starts". So just to clarify, will I be able to boot to GRUB by default this way, without having to edit the boot order in BIOS?

Comment: @user7952 I think if you are installing to disk you replace the windows bootloader with the grub . So no device change in BIOS I guess.